# Inyectar variable desde dentro de la propia consulta

Tags: laravel

Es un sistema de encuestas que esta vinculado a los posts. Mayoritariamente las encuestas serán tipo Si/No pero hay que dejar la posibilidad de que la encuesta sea de múltiples opciones. De ahí la tabla surveyType .

Aqui los modelos y sus relaciones

**Post**

```
 -id
 -survey_id

    public function survey()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
    }
```

**Surveys**

```
id
survey_type_id

public function surveyOptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Survey_options::class);
}
    
public function surveyType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Survey_type::class);
}
    
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

**Survey_types**

```
id

public function surveyOptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Survey_options::class);
}
```

**Survey_options**

```
id
survey_type_id

public function values()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Option_value::class);
}
```

**options_values**

```
survey_options_id
survey_id

public function surveyOptions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Survey_options::class);
}

Survey_Survey_options (pivot)

survey_id
survey_options_id
```

Seguramente mi consulta es muy estúpida, pero necesito aclararla porque si no se puede hacer esto tengo que buscar otra opción.

La duda es si existe alguna posibilidad de utilizar una variable desde dentro de la propia consulta, es decir , de su propia respuesta, por ejemplo:

```
$posts = Post::with([
             'survey' => function ($query) {
                 $query->withCount('totalSurveys');
             },
             'survey.surveyOptions',
             'survey.surveyOptions' => function ($query) {
                 $query->withCount('values')->where('survey_id', $survey_id);
             },
             'image',
             'categories'
           ])
           ->withCount('comments')
           ->get();
```

$survey_id no existe fuera de la consulta, debería de venir de la propia respuesta de cada 'survey', no se si me he explicado bien , si es viable o es una estupidez.

Quizás lo estoy planteando mal, perdón por mi ignorancia, pero el resultado final tiene que ser:  una consulta con  eager loading para que me traiga todos los posts con survey, surveyOptions, withCount comentarios y options_values de cada surveyOptions. La consulta de arriba funciona todo bien excepto el total de values.

seria algo tipo así:

```
$post->survey->surveyOptions[x]->totalValues
```

Estoy planteándome crear una tabla pivote entre surveyOptions y totalValues. Creo que esto solucionaría el problema. Existe otra opcion?

Perdón por mi ignorancia

Comment: La consulta que has puesto en cuestión no sería: 
`$posts = Post::with('categories')->whereId($post_id)->get();`
¿Tu pregunta esta enfocada a algun caso de uso concreto?

Comment: Si, es para una consulta mas compleja, edito la pregunta y lo detallo ahi.

Comment: `survey` es una relación de `Post` y `surveyOptions` una relación de `survey`? ¿Estás seguro que `image` es una relación y no un campo?

Comment: @Alberto yo no entiendo la duda ¿puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: @ffflabs he editado la pregunta y añadido los modelos, sus relaciones y la logica que necesito. 'image' es una tabla polimorfica que esta relacionada con los posts . Gracias

Comment: @betaM he añadido mas detalles. gracias

Comment: Quedé muchísimo más confundido. Un post es como un artículo en un blog al cual puedes adosarle una encuesta? O lo has modelado como que cada respuesta de un encuestado se almacena como Post?

Comment: @ffflabs un post es como un articulo de blog. al que se le vincula una encuesta. Un post solo puede tener una encuesta. Pero una encuesta puede vincularse a muchos posts.

Comment: Tu duda inicial es sobre hacer llegar el ID de la encuesta al modelo `Option_value`, Pero este modelo ya tiene un campo `survery_id`. En tu primer closure podrías añadir `$query->with('surveyOptions')->withCount('surveyOptions')`  y llegar a ese modelo

Comment: Si, pero el problema es que la tabla surveyOptions tiene todas las opciones de las encuestas disponibles, por ejemplo ( Si, no, opcion1, opcion2 ) si hago el withCount me trae el total de todas las encuestas y lo que necesito es el total de cada opcion disponible en cada encuesta. Ten presente que por ejemplo un Si puede estar disponible en multitud de encuestas.Entonces lo que necesito es traer el total de votos de una opcion pero a su vez de la propia encuesta.  Lo se, un sistema de encuestas es un autentico dolor de cabeza

Comment: ¿Tu ER es posts--NN--surveys--1N--survey_options?

Comment: No, es posts--N1--surveys--1N--survey_options